# Sort an array of objects by an objects value

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have an array of objects that I parse from a JSON. My JSON looks like this;

```
- message: [

   -{
     movie_id: 30,
     movie_name: "Scream",
     category_name: "Horror"

     },
   -{ 
      movie_id: 31,
      movie_name: "Avengers",
      category_name: "Action"

     },
   -{
     movie_id: 32,
     movie_name: "Friday the 13th",
     category_name: "Horror"

     },
   -{ 
      movie_id: 33,
      movie_name: "The ring",
      category_name: "Horror"

     },
   -{
     movie_id: 34,
     movie_name: "Die Hard",
     category_name: "Action"

     },
   -{ 
      movie_id: 35,
      movie_name: "The ring 2",
      category_name: "Horror"

     },
  ....
```

Its a JSON array of movies that contains many movies. What I am unable to do is parse each object and arrange them by category_name in an array, so all the "horror" will be grouped together, all the action, and all the romance etc etc. However...I need to be able to place a String value at the start of each category. So the array might look like this:

```
Index
0       "Horror"
1        Movie Object
2        Movie Object
3        Movie Object
4        "Romance"
5        Movie Object
6        Movie Object
7        "Action"
8        Movie Object
9        Movie Object
10       Movie Object
```

I have movie object with the following paramters;

```
 NSString *movie_id
 NSString * movie_name
 NSString *category_name
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use a `NSDictionary`. The key is your category name and then the value is a custom array with your objects

Comment: @Mike_NotGuilty the final object needs to be an array

Comment: So you want an array with two different data types? A custom object and a string?!

Comment: @Mike_NotGuilty Yes...crazy I know, when its used in code there is a conditioal statement that uses `isKindOfClass` to check the object

Comment: @DevC have you tried my answer May be this what you want.

Comment: @iHulk I haven't yet as I am away from work, I will try first thing in the morning. Looks very good.

Comment: What you are attempting to do -- inserting strings into an array of objects -- is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Seems likely this should not be your approach. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons never heard of the term code smell. I have to create a picker view from an array. Within the picker the category name needs to be above the corresponding services. So the way I thought of doing it was when setting the titles in the picker view, check if the object at index is of class string, if so this is the header, and should be in bold, else show the service name. If the class is of string then it is not selectable, only the objects are selectable. Do you understand my problem? if there is a better way I am open to improving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose You have your array message then you can arrange them as

```
NSArray *categories = [message valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.category_name"];
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString *categoryName in categories)
{
    NSArray *groupArray = [message filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category_name = %@", categoryName]];
    [results addObject:categoryName];
    [results addObjectsFromArray:groupArray];
}
```

and your final array I mean results will be

```
(
        Horror,
        {
        "category_name" = Horror;
        "movie_id" = 30;
        "movie_name" = Scream;
    },
        {
        " movie_name" = "Friday the 13th";
        "category_name" = Horror;
        "movie_id" = 32;
    },
        {
        "category_name" = Horror;
        "movie_id" = 33;
        "movie_name" = "The ring";
    },
        {
        "category_name" = Horror;
        "movie_id" = 35;
        "movie_name" = "The ring 2";
    },
    Action,
        {
        "category_name" = Action;
        "movie_id" = 31;
        "movie_name" = Avengers;
    },
        {
        "category_name" = Action;
        "movie_id" = 34;
        "movie_name" = "Die Hard";
    }
)
```

Hope this is what you want.
But this not a good coding practice, to have different data types(string and dictionary) in same array. so you should parse them like this

```
NSArray *categories = [message valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.category_name"];
    NSMutableDictionary *results = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (NSString *categoryName in categories)
    {
        NSArray *groupArray = [message filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category_name = %@", categoryName]];
        [results setObject:groupArray forKey:categoryName];
    }
```

and your result will be.

```
{
    Action =     (
                {
            "category_name" = Action;
            "movie_id" = 31;
            "movie_name" = Avengers;
        },
                {
            "category_name" = Action;
            "movie_id" = 34;
            "movie_name" = "Die Hard";
        }
    );
    Horror =     (
                {
            "category_name" = Horror;
            "movie_id" = 30;
            "movie_name" = Scream;
        },
                {
            " movie_name" = "Friday the 13th";
            "category_name" = Horror;
            "movie_id" = 32;
        },
                {
            "category_name" = Horror;
            "movie_id" = 33;
            "movie_name" = "The ring";
        },
                {
            "category_name" = Horror;
            "movie_id" = 35;
            "movie_name" = "The ring 2";
        }
    );
}
```

Now choose whatever you want.

Comment: @DevC First you need to find the unique categories of movies like Action and horror, then loop on your these categories array, again filter the json array on the basis of each category and then save them one by one as you want. Either in a same array or in a dictionary with key as your category.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a slightly different structure for the parsed data.

Rather than an array of mixed strings and objects, why not create a dictionary (using the category names as keys) of arrays? Just iterate through your original JSON. For each movie object, check to see if the key exists for that category name. If it does not, add a new array as the value for that category name. Then add the movie object to the array.

Your final dictionary would be something like this:

`@{ @"Horror" : @[obj1, obj2, obj 3], 
    @"Romance" : @[obj4, obj5, obj 6],
    @"Action" : @[obj7, obj8, obj 9] }`

That way you can iterate through each category, and also iterate through the movies is each category